# Active class isn't applying on a navigation list

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/DG3r9/5/

I'm trying to make the first link "active" as if that is the current page and that navigation option is highlighted.

I used this HTML:

```
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="active" id=""> <a href="#"><span></span>test1</a></li>
        <li id="test"><a href="#"><span></span>test2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
.navigation li a:hover, .navigation li a.active {
    background-color:#495C6D;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the first item isn't highlighted as it should be please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DG3r9/6/)

The active class is on your `li` not `a`, change to:

```
.navigation li a:hover, .navigation li.active a{
    background-color:#495C6D;
}
```

Or move `class='active'` to the `a`